# ASE Syabse server version with Delphi and dbExpress

Tags: delphi, sybase, sap-ase, dbexpress

I try to get the version of an ASE Sybase version, using Delphi 2009 and dbExpress

My code is

```
with SQLQuery1 do
  begin
    SQL.Text := 'select @@version';
    Open;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(FieldList.Fields[0].Value);
    Close;
  end;
```

The Open statement raises an exception with message "SQLQuery1: field name missing".
What intrigues me is tha t with ADO, the same code works quite well and i get sommething like this:

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0/EBF 21204 SMP SP50 /P/X64/Windows Server/ase157sp5x/3286/64-     bit/OPT/Thu Jul 11 16:47:22 2013

I also get the same error with this query

```
SQL.Text := 'select count(*) from myDB..sysobjects where name = ''db_vers'''
```

Comment: I have the same error with this query

SQL.Text := 'select count(*) from myDB..sysobjects where name = ''db_vers''';

Comment: You could try `@@version_number` instead - maybe it's the text that's throwing things off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an alias as below

```
select @@version as version
```

It should work also for second query.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget you can also vote ;)

Comment: And it work for second case to

count(*) as MyCount from myDB..sysobjects where name = ''db_vers''';